# Erase duplicate pairs from list

Tags: haskell

I have a list of pairs and I want to erase all the duplicates in the list. So for example I have [(1,7),(7,1),(2,3),(3,4),(4,3)] and after using the function I would get [(1,7),(2,3),(3,4)].

Is there already a function that does something like this or an easy way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`nubBy`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=nubBy) function eliminates duplicate elements from a list using the function you provide for elements comparison.

```
nubBy (\x y -> (fst x == snd y && snd x == fst y) || (x == y)) [(1,7),(7,1),(2,3),(3,4),(4,3)]
[(1,7),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

Comment: `nubBy` isn't terribly efficient, though, is it?

Comment: @user3217013, without a known `Ord`, `Hashable`, or similar constraint, it's the best you can do.

Comment: @dfeuer Right. I was assuming that we were dealing with `Integer`s.

Answer (score 2):

You could reorder each tuple so that you always have the smaller element on the left and the larger on the right. Then you can sort your list and take one element from each run of equal elements. This is how I would do it

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.List (sort, group)

dedup = map head . group . sort . map (uncurry min &&& uncurry max)
```

Answer (score 2):

If order is unimportant, you could just choose the version of the tuple with the smaller element followed by the larger element as the 'canonical' representation of each element, and then either sort the list and remove adjacent duplicates, or run them through a set (both take O(nlogn) time).

Here is the latter solution:

```
import Data.Set
removeDuplicates xs = toList (fromList (canonical xs))
    where canonical [] = []
          canonical ((a,b):t) = (if a < b then (a, b) else (b, a)) : (canonical t)
```